# Passing classes/objects/data? between two forms

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli

I am currently working on a C++ project which requires me to pass data from one form to the other. In this case, the user will create an account on CreateAccount Form (`Create_Account.h`) with a username and password. This username and password will be stored as private attributes of a object (lets call it `user`) and he will proceed to a Login Form (`Login.h`). However, I cannot get the system to verify the entered password on this form with the earlier one. I have sort of figure out that I have to pass the object(`user`) to this login form so that I can verify the username and password entered with the private attributes of the object(`user`). However, I'm not very sure of the syntax on how to pass in objects to forms. (I'm only familiar with passing objects through functions)

I am new to this language and will really appreciate help on it.

Below is the code which I have written.

```
**//CreateAccount.h**

#pragma once
#include "user2.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ExpenseTracker.h"
#include "User_Login.h"
#include <string>
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>

namespace EzXpns2 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Create_Account
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Create_Account : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Create_Account(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Create_Account()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnCreateNewAccount;
    protected: 

    protected: 
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  txtBxPassword;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  lblPassword;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  txtBxUsername;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  lblUsername;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  txtBxReenterPassword;

    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
    //private: System::Windows::Forms:User_Login^ userlogin; 
    //private User_Login^ UserLogin;


    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->btnCreateNewAccount = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->txtBxPassword = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->lblPassword = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->txtBxUsername = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->lblUsername = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->txtBxReenterPassword = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // btnCreateNewAccount
            // 
            this->btnCreateNewAccount->Location = System::Drawing::Point(147, 147);
            this->btnCreateNewAccount->Name = L"btnCreateNewAccount";
            this->btnCreateNewAccount->Size = System::Drawing::Size(126, 23);
            this->btnCreateNewAccount->TabIndex = 3;
            this->btnCreateNewAccount->Text = L"Create New Account";
            this->btnCreateNewAccount->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->btnCreateNewAccount->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Create_Account::btnCreateNewAccount_Click);
            // 
            // txtBxPassword
            // 
            this->txtBxPassword->Location = System::Drawing::Point(147, 68);
            this->txtBxPassword->Name = L"txtBxPassword";
            this->txtBxPassword->Size = System::Drawing::Size(126, 20);
            this->txtBxPassword->TabIndex = 1;
            this->txtBxPassword->UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
            // 
            // lblPassword
            // 
            this->lblPassword->AutoSize = true;
            this->lblPassword->Location = System::Drawing::Point(26, 73);
            this->lblPassword->Name = L"lblPassword";
            this->lblPassword->Size = System::Drawing::Size(56, 13);
            this->lblPassword->TabIndex = 12;
            this->lblPassword->Text = L"Password:";
            // 
            // txtBxUsername
            // 
            this->txtBxUsername->Location = System::Drawing::Point(149, 27);
            this->txtBxUsername->Name = L"txtBxUsername";
            this->txtBxUsername->Size = System::Drawing::Size(126, 20);
            this->txtBxUsername->TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // lblUsername
            // 
            this->lblUsername->AutoSize = true;
            this->lblUsername->Location = System::Drawing::Point(24, 29);
            this->lblUsername->Name = L"lblUsername";
            this->lblUsername->Size = System::Drawing::Size(86, 13);
            this->lblUsername->TabIndex = 10;
            this->lblUsername->Text = L"Enter Username:";
            // 
            // txtBxReenterPassword
            // 
            this->txtBxReenterPassword->Location = System::Drawing::Point(147, 100);
            this->txtBxReenterPassword->Name = L"txtBxReenterPassword";
            this->txtBxReenterPassword->Size = System::Drawing::Size(126, 20);
            this->txtBxReenterPassword->TabIndex = 2;
            this->txtBxReenterPassword->UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(26, 105);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 13);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 15;
            this->label1->Text = L"Re-enter Password:";
            // 
            // Create_Account
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(309, 188);
            this->Controls->Add(this->txtBxReenterPassword);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->btnCreateNewAccount);
            this->Controls->Add(this->txtBxPassword);
            this->Controls->Add(this->lblPassword);
            this->Controls->Add(this->txtBxUsername);
            this->Controls->Add(this->lblUsername);
            this->Name = L"Create_Account";
            this->Text = L"Welcome to EzXpns -Create Account";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion

private: System::Void btnCreateNewAccount_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

                 ExpenseTracker *myTracker  = new ExpenseTracker();
                 string strUsername, strPassword, strReenterPassword; 
                 bool checkPassword = false;

                 System::String^ str1 = txtBxUsername->Text;
                 strUsername = marshal_as<string>(str1);
                 //convert system string to string

                 System::String^ str2 = txtBxPassword->Text;    
                 strPassword = marshal_as<string>(str2);

                 System::String^ str3 = txtBxReenterPassword->Text; 
                 strReenterPassword = marshal_as<string>(str3);

                 if (strPassword  == strReenterPassword) 
                     checkPassword = true;

                 if (checkPassword)
                 {
                     User *newUser = new User(strUsername, strReenterPassword);
                     (*myTracker).addUser(newUser);
                     this->Hide();
                     User_Login^ testDialog = gcnew User_Login;
                     testDialog->Show();
                 }
                 else
                    MessageBox::Show("Please re-enter your password.\n\nThe password you entered do not match.\nPlease try again.",
         "Create User Failure", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Warning);
         }
};
}

//UserLogin.h
#pragma once
#include "user2.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ExpenseTracker.h"
#include "Create_Account.h"
#include "Login.h"
#include <string>
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>

namespace EzXpns2 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace msclr::interop;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for User_Login
    /// </summary>
    public ref class User_Login : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        User_Login(void)//ExpenseTracker *myPtrTracker)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
            //CreateAccountForm = CreateAcct;
            //ExpenseTracker *myTracker = myPtrTracker;
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~User_Login()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnLogin;
    protected: 
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  txtBxPassword;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  lblPassword;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  txtBxUsername;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  lblUsername;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Form^ CreateAccountForm;


    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->btnLogin = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->txtBxPassword = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->lblPassword = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->txtBxUsername = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->lblUsername = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // btnLogin
            // 
            this->btnLogin->Location = System::Drawing::Point(80, 110);
            this->btnLogin->Name = L"btnLogin";
            this->btnLogin->Size = System::Drawing::Size(126, 23);
            this->btnLogin->TabIndex = 9;
            this->btnLogin->Text = L"Login";
            this->btnLogin->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->btnLogin->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &User_Login::btnLogin_Click);
            // 
            // txtBxPassword
            // 
            this->txtBxPassword->Location = System::Drawing::Point(80, 65);
            this->txtBxPassword->Name = L"txtBxPassword";
            this->txtBxPassword->Size = System::Drawing::Size(126, 20);
            this->txtBxPassword->TabIndex = 8;
            this->txtBxPassword->UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
            this->txtBxPassword->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &User_Login::txtBxPassword_TextChanged);
            // 
            // lblPassword
            // 
            this->lblPassword->AutoSize = true;
            this->lblPassword->Location = System::Drawing::Point(20, 68);
            this->lblPassword->Name = L"lblPassword";
            this->lblPassword->Size = System::Drawing::Size(56, 13);
            this->lblPassword->TabIndex = 7;
            this->lblPassword->Text = L"Password:";
            this->lblPassword->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &User_Login::lblPassword_Click);
            // 
            // txtBxUsername
            // 
            this->txtBxUsername->Location = System::Drawing::Point(82, 24);
            this->txtBxUsername->Name = L"txtBxUsername";
            this->txtBxUsername->Size = System::Drawing::Size(126, 20);
            this->txtBxUsername->TabIndex = 6;
            this->txtBxUsername->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &User_Login::txtBxUsername_TextChanged);
            // 
            // lblUsername
            // 
            this->lblUsername->AutoSize = true;
            this->lblUsername->Location = System::Drawing::Point(18, 24);
            this->lblUsername->Name = L"lblUsername";
            this->lblUsername->Size = System::Drawing::Size(58, 13);
            this->lblUsername->TabIndex = 5;
            this->lblUsername->Text = L"Username:";
            this->lblUsername->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &User_Login::lblUsername_Click);
            // 
            // User_Login
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(231, 155);
            this->Controls->Add(this->btnLogin);
            this->Controls->Add(this->txtBxPassword);
            this->Controls->Add(this->lblPassword);
            this->Controls->Add(this->txtBxUsername);
            this->Controls->Add(this->lblUsername);
            this->Name = L"User_Login";
            this->Text = L"Welcome to EzXpns";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &User_Login::User_Login_Load);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void btnLogin_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

                 //User myUser;
                 //ExpenseTracker myTracker;

                 System::String^ str1 = txtBxUsername->Text;
                 string strUsername = marshal_as<string>(str1);
                 //convert system string to string

                 System::String^ str2 = txtBxPassword->Text;    
                 string strPassword = marshal_as<string>(str2);
                 bool success = false;
                 success = (*myTracker).login(strUsername, strPassword);
                 if (success)
                 {
                        this->Hide();
                        Login^ testDialog = gcnew Login;
                        testDialog->Show();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                      MessageBox::Show("Please re-enter your password.\n\nThe password you entered is incorrect.\nPlease try again (make sure your caps lock is off).",
         "Login Failure", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Warning);
                 }
             }
private: System::Void lblUsername_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             }
private: System::Void lblPassword_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             }
private: System::Void txtBxPassword_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             }
private: System::Void txtBxUsername_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             }
private: System::Void User_Login_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

         }
};
}

//ExpenseTracker.h 
#ifndef _EXPENSETRACKER_H
#define _EXPENSETRACKER_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
//#include <iostream>
#include "user2.h"

using namespace std;

class ExpenseTracker
{
private:
    vector<User*> allMyUsers;

public:
    ExpenseTracker(); //empty constructor
    void addUser(User*);
    int findUser(string);
    bool login(string, string);
};

#endif;
```

Comment: Admitting I haven't read anything thoroughly, define a static class in your namespace and use it to pass arguments, or define a constructor which accepts a reference or a pointer to your objects to exchange data.

Comment: Your code is rather long and therefore unlikely to be red by many people. However be informed that what your have here is not standard C++, but C++/CLI, a Microsoft extension to support writing C++-ish code for the .NET framework. I added Tags to lead your question to a broader audience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you pass data from one form to another depends on the hierarchy of your application. It would be the "parent" class that instances both of your forms that receives the data from the first one and sends it to the second one. It could be done via the constructors, or accessor functions, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when working with Forms (OOP) you should really think of forms as classes (like ones you create to help application tasks). So, in this particular case when I have to pass data through Forms, I usually create Properties. You should only decide where to put it and how to use it.

For example: if I am in a Main form and will call a Login form so it has to return a username and password to the Main form, then I would create two properties in the Login form called Username and Passwords (as string, maybe). You could also create public strings so you can access directly from the outside (from Main form) but this is not so nice from OOP perspective since you can think of Username and Password as 2 data properties from Login class.

Finally, with public properties you can easily retrieve these info from Login form. I think that should apply to your needs.

```
public ref class Login {
    private string username, password;
    public string Username { get { return username; } }
    public string Password { get { return password; } }

    public void Show {
        //Do your stuff and then user clicks OK
        username = ...//soemthing like Textbox1.Text
        password = ...//same here
    }
}
public ref class Main{

    public void method {
         Login frmLogin = new Login();
         frmLogin.Show();
         MessageBox.Show("User: " + frmLogin.Username + " and Password: " + frmLogin.Password);
    }
}
```

I did not test or write something that works (with inherited class from Forms and ShowDialog() stuff) but that is the pretty basic idea, you should get it.